# PassengerDetailsRQ return EndTransactionLLSRQ: ITINERARY REQUIRED TO COMPLETE TRANSACTION

Tags: sabre

I am receiving this error when trying to retrive an empty PNR / shell PNR where only passenger details are provided.

```
EndTransactionLLSRQ: ITINERARY REQUIRED TO COMPLETE TRANSACTION
```

I have read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a 'shell' PNR is not allowed unless there are active segments in the record. You can get around this by creating an OTH or Miscellaneous segment that contains text only and sends no message to any carriers. That API is called "MiscSegmentSellLLSRQ" and the documentation can be found at [this link](https://beta.developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/book/Sell_Miscellaneous_Segments).

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there a way to add secure flight data to the shell also or should it contain the actual segments first? if it should contain the segments first how do i add it later on? by adding the PNR on the TravelItineraryAddInfo?